# SP 2016 Single Line of Text greyed out in Datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, disabled-input, datasheet

I have an InfoPath form library with multiple promoted fields. The fields in question are Single Line of Text fields. The fields are all greyed out in the Datasheet view. I am used to only seeing this with multiple lines of text and rich text. The library doesn't require content approval or require check out. Any ideas? This is SharePoint 2016 on premise and InfoPath 2013.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a minute since I modified a library form. You have to perform a full publish and when promoting the field, make sure to modify the promotion and select "Allow users to edit data in this field by using a datasheet or properties page"